# Want to make an AJAX call after x sec time interval to load data from the table and append that data into a div

Tags: php, ajax

I am trying to create a chat system using php and ajax. I started the ajax request when the user hit the send button and after that the request will be called after 5 sec automatically. I want fetch the latest entry from the database. I am passing a last item id "tid".

I am getting the data from the database after the last id but it appending my div the same data until I entered a new record.

```
function startajax()
{

   var usfrnd = $("#username").text();

   var data = 'lastid=' + tid + '&usfrnd=' + usfrnd;

  $.ajax({

        type: "POST",
           url: "includes/wow_message.php",
            data: data,
            //dataType: "JSON",

                success: function(msg){ 

$("#msgbody").append(msg); 
console.log(msg);


         },

         complete: function() {

      setTimeout(startajax, 5000);
    }

  });



}



php code.

<?php


 include '../include/database.php';


 session_start();

$username =  $_SESSION['uName'];


if(isset($_POST['lastid'], $_POST['usfrnd']))

{


$lastid = $_POST['lastid'];
$sent_to = $_POST['usfrnd'];


 $qry2 = "select * from msg_tab where (((sent_by= '$username' AND sent_to='$sent_to') OR (sent_by= '$sent_to' AND sent_to='$username')) AND $lastid < msg_id) ORDER BY msg_id ASC";
       $res = mysqli_query($conn, $qry2);


      if (mysqli_num_rows($res) > 0) {

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {

$message  = $row['msg'];
$msg_id = $row['msg_id'];
$sent_by = $row['sent_by'];

  echo ' <tr  data-msg-id="'.$msg_id.'">
                        <td><span class="subject">'.$sent_by.'</span></td>     <td><span class="subject">'.$message.'</span></td>

                            </tr>';


    }
}





}




?>
```

Comment: use the limit clause of mysql

Comment: Not what you asking for but for things like chat I recommend using websockets instead. Ratchet is a good asynchronous library for php. https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-quickly-build-a-chat-app-with-ratchet/

Comment: you have to update that `tid` on every ajax call otherwise it will bring all the record again and again. so update the last id to that variable

Comment: Fairy not sure how to update that tid do I need to use tid++ under success ?

Comment: the query is running fine for me it is fetching the record > lst id. but it is appending the same data to my div at every ajax call . @AmitGaud

Answer (score 0):

If you want create chat maybe you should use ex. WebSocket.
Send request in some time interval in my opinion is no so good solution.

Comment: i don't know much about websocket could you please provide me a reference for that @Jaroslaw

Comment: websocket can use to communicate from server to client. Client send one request "handshake" and wait for request form server. Read:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket
ex. https://github.com/ghedipunk/PHP-Websockets